# How to model conditional moments using an additive model

Tags: regression, modeling, generalized-linear-model, conditional-expectation, generalized-moments

Let's say that I have the data set $(X,Y)$ where $X$ is a p-dimensional variable and $Y$ is uni dimensional. I'm interested in the following model:

$$
    \theta_y = E(Y|X) \\
    \theta_{y^2} = E(Y^2|X) \\
    \theta_{y^3} = E(Y^3|X) \\
    \theta_{y^4} = E(Y^4|X)
$$

where the components of $X$ enter the model additively.

I'm interested on the left hand side for a posterior analysis. I'm barely aware of generalized additive models but I haven't used them before. What I need are pointers to theories and concepts that I should look to model and solve this problem.